# Index out of range exception while iterating through list c#

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, controller

This is my controller code :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string priceMin, string priceMax)
    {
        lstEventType = HttpRuntime.Cache["EventType"] as List<string>;
        if (lstEventType == null || !lstEventType.Any())
        {
            lstEventType = new List<string>();
            lst = artistModel.fillDropDown();
            lstEventType = lst.Where(p => p.lookupType == "EventType").Select(q => q.lookupValue).ToList();
            HttpRuntime.Cache["EventType"] = lstEventType;
        }
        ViewData["EventType"] = lstEventType;
        artistList = artistModel.displayArtist();    
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceMin))
        {
            aSession.priceMin = priceMin;
            ViewData["priceMin"] = priceMin;
            artistList = artistList.Where(p => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.strHiddenCost) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(p.strHiddenCost)) >= Convert.ToInt32(priceMin)).ToList();
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceMax))
        {
            aSession.priceMax = priceMax;
            ViewData["priceMax"] = priceMax;
            artistList = artistList.Where(p => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.strHiddenCost) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(p.strHiddenCost)) <= Convert.ToInt32(priceMax)).ToList();
        }         
        return View(artistList);
    }
```

If this artistList returns non value then I am not getting any error . But if the artistList  is returning null the below portion of code in view is throwing exception. I am not able to figure out how this artistList is affecting viewdata["EventType"].

Below is my code in view

```
@{
   List<string> EventTypes = ViewData["EventType"] as List<string>;
        foreach (string eventType in EventTypes)
          {    
            <li><a> <span class="pull-right"></span>@eventType</a></li>
          }
   }
```

While iterating through this loop I am getting index out of range exception. If my controller is returning a non null list to this view then its working fine. But if the controller is returning empty list to view this iteration fails.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have an entry for "EventType" in your ViewData

Comment: i am getting 3 rows in the viewdata.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown that would case that error. Debug you code! And you have invalid html (a `li` element cannot be a child of `em` element)

Comment: this em is just for this stackoverflow . <pre> and <em> tag is actually not present in my code .

Answer (score 0):

Variable naming is important, try EventTypeList instead of EventTypes.
Also, since you are using a foreach, you should use a nullcheck.

```
@{
    List<string> EventTypeList= ViewData["EventType"] as List<string>;
    if (EventTypeList != null && EventTypeList.Count > 0){
        foreach (string eventType in EventTypeList)
        {
            <li><a> <span class="pull-right">@eventType</span></a></li>
        }
    }
}
```

The added nullcheck will fix your problem of what occurs when the controller sends an empty list.

Comment: for me this EventTypeList  is never null. So didn't put any null check . controller is returning another list to my strongly typed view .

Comment: I have updated the answer, if you are returning an empty list instead of a null list, put a .Count check as well.

Comment: "if the controller is returning empty list to view " the .Count check will fix that problem. What is the other issue?

Comment: I have run your code with my modifications and can not break it. It works fine. The solution to your problem is a nullcheck and Count. If there is another problem then I am not seeing it. Best of luck.

Comment: did you try any condition when the artistList is null ?